# Looping over JSON data in Python multiple times

Tags: python, json, dictionary, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I am trying to loop over JSON data and get **five** ids, because there are always five of them on one page. For now I can get only the last one. How can I get five ids? 
Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

source = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html#REVIEWS').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

pattern = re.compile(r'window.__WEB_CONTEXT__={pageManifest:(\{.*\})};')
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
dictData = pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
jsonData = json.loads(dictData)


def get_ids():

    id_dict = {}
    for locations in jsonData['urqlCache']['669061039']['data']['locations']:
        reviews = locations['reviewListPage']['reviews']
        for data in reviews:
            id_dict["id"] = data['id']

    return id_dict

def main():

    id = get_ids()
    print(id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output should look like this:

```
{'id': 732967109}
{'id': 726974284}
{'id': 725596487}
{'id': 725202773}
{'id': 720102359}
```

Thank you for all suggestions!

Comment: `id_dict["id"] = data['id']`  This just overrides the value of `id_dict['id']` each time through the loop.  Perhaps you meant something like `id_dict[data['id']] = data`?  Or perhaps you want a list, not a dict.  I don't know.  When debugging Python code first experiment with smaller parts of your problem using the minimal amount of code.  As far as I can tell your problem has nothing to do with more complicated things like BeautifulSoup or JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I would like to have five different dictionaries or one list with five dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the keys everytime, you need unique keys.

Try something like:

```
count = 0
for data in reviews:
    id_dict[count] = data['id']
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to add ids to a list

```
id_dict["id"] = []
for data in reviews:
    id_dict["id"].append(data['id'])
```

Comment: You're assigning literal lists, you cant do that here.